# window.open javascript window not showing complete content

Tags: javascript, html

Im using the window.open command to open a new browser window, but when it happens it doesnt render the complete height of the page, even Im adding a height=1600 it only shows the complete height of the window plus like 150px, any idea?

```
<div>
    <a href="myUrl" onclick="window.open(this.ref,'_blank','width=850,height=1600'); return false;">MyUrl</a>
</div>
```

Comment: are you specifying scrollbars=1 in your window.open statement ? That way, if the content of your page exceeds the dimensions of your opened window, you will at least be able to scroll

Comment: What do you mean with _the complete height of the window plus like 150px_?

Comment: Thanks it did it, I just needed to lookup to the CSS too.

Comment: ok great - feel free to accept my answer below then - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add scrollbars = 1 to your window.open statement

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gsiry01/UJ6WE/

```
<div>
        <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','_blank','width=850,height=1600, scrollbars=1'); return false;">test</a>
</div>
```

You can additionally set resizable=1 which will also allow you to manually resize the window that opens

Comment: Now I have 2 sets of scrollbars

Comment: You should have a **real** URL in the `href` attribute rather than `#`. If the script for some reason or other doesn't run properly, you have pointlessly created a usability problem.